# Is it better to use more measurements or just use tags for performance

Tags: database, performance, database-design, schema, influxdb

I am using InfluxDb for logging measurements of many power plants. Currently I am using one measurement with power_plant as a tag and than fields for measurements. Is it better to have different measurement for every power plant or just use tags. I have concerns about the performance when there will be terabyte or more data in this one measurement?

At the moment i have structure like this (all power plants data in one measurement and using tags powerplant and device to query data)

```
private static $invertersMeasurement = [
    'value' => NULL,
    'tags' => [
        'power_plant' => NULL,
        'device' => NULL,
        'logger_ip' => NULL,
        ],
    'fields' => [
        'type' => NULL,
        'e_total' => NULL,
        'status' => NULL,
        'error' => NULL,
        'temp' => NULL,
        'pac' => NULL,
        'pdc1' => NULL,
        'udc1' => NULL,
        'idc1' => NULL,
        'pdc2' => NULL,
        'udc2' => NULL,
        'idc2' => NULL,
        'pdc3' => NULL,
        'udc3' => NULL,
        'idc3' => NULL,
        'pdc4' => NULL,
        'udc4' => NULL,
        'idc4' => NULL
        ],
    'time' => NULL
];
```

Is it better to remove power plant tag and store data for every power plant in a different measurement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q:** Is it better to use more measurements?

**A:** Advantage of having all data within one measurement is that, it is much easier for you to perform data aggregation when the points are all put inside one place.

However this is a problem prior to influxdb `v1.7.0` where cross measurement joins are not possible at all. This means that you cannot do data aggregation between data points from different measurements.

**Note:** As of now, only `flux`, the new influx 2.0 query language would allow you to do cross measurement joins.

In most cases if you design your scheme correctly by storing the right type of point data into the appropriate measurement, you shoudn't have to do cross measurement joins.

Looking at your fields, I can see some data types like temperature. Maybe they can be put inside a different measurement? This is so that developers, especially newly hired ones, can discover the data much easier?

This also make your measurement much organised. A single measurement dataset can look messy when you have a temperature data coming in at a minute interval and some of your fields having interval of 2mins. This means that on certain occasion a particular data row would only always have temperature field and not others.

You need to handle this sort of edge cases. Do you do `linear` interpolation or not?

Not sure what those ucp idc 1,2,3 and 4 fields are. If they are somehow associated then they should be kept in a measurement alone. Associated in the sense that with the combination of certain fields e.g. ucp1 and ucp2, you can work out whether or not the data can be made sense out of it to tell you something. For instance high temperature value + low ucp value means machine failure?

I would go for grouping your data in the correct measurement, otherwise there is really no need to have `measurement` in influxdb.

Comment: Thanx for answer. But I will newer need to cross measurements joins. I am always needing data for only one power plant. I also have sensors measurement where i store sensors data. Here in inverters measurement (this example) I store data from inverters. I will always have full row and never only some data, because loggers create 2 files (sensors and inverters) and send with ftp push to my server where I hav eparser to decode data and save it to influx. Udc 1,2,3 is voltage on string 1 2 and 3. idc is current and pdc is power. And temp is the temperature of device.

Comment: many thanks for the insight sounds like you're working on a software for some solar systems of a power plant or something.

Comment: Yes I work for a company that do solar power plants. I am building them monitoring system. It is quite awesome project :)

Answer (score 0):

No, keep tags, because some visualization tools (e.g. Grafana) has better support for tags than measurements + filtering by tag is fast and cheap (if you don't have high cardinality tags). Anyway, your schema looks good to me.